# t-SNE on a small sparse matrix

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, sparse, tsne

I performed t-SNE on a this small sparse matrix with 2 identical points:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],   #
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],   #
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I expected these two points would still be identical in the 2 dimensional embedding but they are not. Why is this?